# how to cast the output of Count() in django to FloatField in django 1.8

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I am using django 1.8.

I have two models:-

```
class Query(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    title = models.TextField()
    details = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    post_score=models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    ....

class Tags(models.Model):
    """docstring for Tags"""
    tagname=models.TextField()
grouppostlist=models.ManyToManyField(Query,through='GroupPostsTag',through_fields=('tag','query'))

# and another model(it stores tags for a query)

class GroupPostsTag(models.Model):
    query=models.ForeignKey('Query')
    tag=models.models.ForeignKey('Tags')
```

Now I want to sort queries based on the sum of "number of tags" and query's "post_score".
I am looking for something like this:-

```
tagged_user_posts = Query.objects.filter(Q(tags__id__in=tags_list)).annotate(num_tags=Cast(Count('tags'),models.FloatField())).annotate(post_scores=F('num_tags')+F('post_score')).order_by('-post_scores')
```

[Cast](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#cast) is provided in django 1.10. So what alternative I can use?

Comment: It's open source. You can just copy the [source of `Cast` class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/db/models/functions/base/#Cast) and save it in a file in your project.

Comment: I tried that but it gave me an error:
`TypeError: as_sql() got an unexpected keyword argument 'db_type'`

Comment: I've modified the source code a little and added it in an answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in my comment that you can simply copy the source code of `Cast` class and save it in your projects and use it.

Turns out it wasn't *as simple as that*. You will also need to change the `Cast.as_sql` [as it is in v1.10](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10/django/db/models/expressions.py#L516-L536). And, no need to make a `super` call to `Func.as_sql`.

Just copy the following code and save it in your project. I've tested it and it works.

```
from django.db.models import Func, fields


class Cast(Func):
    """
    Coerce an expression to a new field type.
    """
    function = 'CAST'
    template = '%(function)s(%(expressions)s AS %(db_type)s)'

    mysql_types = {
        fields.CharField: 'char',
        fields.IntegerField: 'signed integer',
        fields.FloatField: 'signed',
    }

    def __init__(self, expression, output_field):
        super(Cast, self).__init__(expression, output_field=output_field)

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection, function=None, template=None, arg_joiner=None, **extra_context):
        if 'db_type' not in extra_context:
            extra_context['db_type'] = self._output_field.db_type(connection)
        connection.ops.check_expression_support(self)
        sql_parts = []
        params = []
        for arg in self.source_expressions:
            arg_sql, arg_params = compiler.compile(arg)
            sql_parts.append(arg_sql)
            params.extend(arg_params)
        data = self.extra.copy()
        data.update(**extra_context)
        # Use the first supplied value in this order: the parameter to this
        # method, a value supplied in __init__()'s **extra (the value in
        # `data`), or the value defined on the class.
        if function is not None:
            data['function'] = function
        else:
            data.setdefault('function', self.function)
        template = template or data.get('template', self.template)
        arg_joiner = arg_joiner or data.get('arg_joiner', self.arg_joiner)
        data['expressions'] = data['field'] = arg_joiner.join(sql_parts)
        return template % data, params


    def as_mysql(self, compiler, connection):
        extra_context = {}
        output_field_class = type(self._output_field)
        if output_field_class in self.mysql_types:
            extra_context['db_type'] = self.mysql_types[output_field_class]
        return self.as_sql(compiler, connection, **extra_context)

    def as_postgresql(self, compiler, connection):
        # CAST would be valid too, but the :: shortcut syntax is more readable.
        return self.as_sql(compiler, connection, template='%(expressions)s::%(db_type)s')
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in question for django 1.10 you can use built-in Cast function. For older versions you can use [Func() expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions)

```
from django.db.models import Count, Func, F, ExpressionWrapper, FloatField
tagged_user_posts = Query.objects.filter(Q(tags__id__in=tags_list)).
    annotate(num_tags=Func(Count('tags'), 
                           template='%(function)s(%(expressions)s AS %(type)s)', 
                           function='Cast', 
                           type='float')
    ).
    annotate(post_scores=ExpressionWrapper(F('num_tags')+F('post_score'), output_field=FloatField())).
    order_by('-post_scores')
```

Comment: it showed an error `FieldError: Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field`

Comment: Wraping sum of F objects with ExpressionWrapper should fix this problem. Try it now.

Answer (score 0):

You could define `Cast` as

```
def Cast(what, as_type):
    if isinstance(as_type, Field):
        as_type = as_type.db_type(connection)
    return Func(
        what,
        template='%(function)s(%(expressions)s AS %(type)s)',
        function='Cast',
        type=as_type,
    )
```